# Freeze First Column of Sharepoint Datasheet View

Tags: dataview

Is there an easy way to freeze the first column of a SharePoint datasheet view.  I have access to SharePoint designer if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in SP2013 it is possible with a pure CSS solution (so some ***CSS skills are required***), you just need to style the JSGrid using one of the existing techniques.

It is usually done in two simple steps:

1. Wrap the table in question into a div or use an existing div if the table is already wrapped. And then arrange it to be scrollable horizontally, e.g. like this:

   ```
   .table-wrapper { 
       overflow-x:scroll;
       overflow-y:visible;
   }
   ```
2. Make the first column non-scrollable, which is usually achieved by applying `position:absolute` to the corresponding TDs, and fixing the paddings if needed.

For example, in JSGrid, the title column is marked with class `ms-vb-title`, so you can use this class for your purpose. Or you can stick with `td:first-child` & `td:nth-child(n)` approach.

Also take a look on existing solutions for this, e.g. these two:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling
- http://jsbin.com/uxecel/4/edit?html,css,output

In SP2010, datasheet view is an ActiveX control, meaning it is sort of a mini- MS Access running inside your browser. Customization capabilities for this control are very limited, and there's no way to access the internals of an ActiveX control from JavaScript. So most likely in SP2010 it is not possible.

Comment: If you add JavaScript to a Calculated Column it will be executed Inside that SP2010 control and you should be able to do anything you want by walking the DOM with parentNode/previousSibling etc. and change styles. Here's how to get JS in a Calculated Column: http://ViewMaster365.com/#How